# How do I select a node in springy.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

javascript noob. I am diving in and managed to get a forced layout diagram setup with this library [springy.js](http://getspringy.com/) . However I don't know how to select a node (I want to do an onclick and trigger some ajax). With the code below (in my html) I keep getting the error that the graph is not defined.

javascript

```
var graphJSON = {"nodes":["1","2","3","4","5","6"],"edges":[["4","3"],["3","4"],["3","3"],["4","4"]]};
jQuery(function(){
  var graph = new Springy.Graph();
  graph.loadJSON(graphJSON);
  var springy = jQuery('#springydemo').springy({
    graph: graph
  });
});

jQuery('#springydemo').springy({ graph: graph, nodeSelected: function(node) {
    alert(node.data.label);
} });
```

html:

```
<canvas id="my_canvas" width="600" height="400" />
```

Here's my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sebastiz/spnvf1q3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hang on sorted it. Had it all wrapped in a jquery. This is what it should look like:

```
var graphJSON = {"nodes":["1","2","3","4","5","6"],"edges":[["4","3"],["3","4"],["3","3"],["4","4"]]};



  var graph = new Springy.Graph();
  graph.loadJSON(graphJSON);
  var springy = jQuery('#springydemo').springy({graph: graph});


jQuery('#springydemo').springy({ graph: graph, nodeSelected: function(node) {
    alert(node.data.label);
} });
```